# Is there any way to increase maximum fuzziness on a fuzzy query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to use elastic search to do a fuzzy query for strings. According to this link (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/common-options.html#fuzziness), the maximum fuzziness allowed is 2, so the query will only return results that are 2 edits away using the Levenshtein Edit Distance. The site says that Fuzzy Like This Query supports fuzzy searches with a fuzziness greater than 2, but so far using the Fuzzy Like This Query has only allowed me to search for results within two edits of the search. Is there any workaround for this constraint?

Comment: If you need a fuzziness greater than 2, you should consider using an ngram analyzer for your text.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this was a bug which was [fixed](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/5374) quite a while back.  Which Elasticsearch version are you using?

For context, the reason why Edit Distance is now limited to [0,1,2] for most Fuzzy operations has to do with [a massive performance improvement of fuzzy/wildcard/regexp matching in Lucene 4 using Finite State Transducers](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html).

Executing a fuzzy query via an FST requires knowing the desired edit-distance at the time the transducer is constructed (at index-time).  This was likely capped at an edit-distance of 2 to keep the FST size requirements manageable.  *But also possibly, because for many applications, an edit-distance of greater than 2 introduces a whole lot of noise*.

The previous fuzzy query implementation required visiting each document to calculate edit distance at query-time and was impractical for large collections.

It sounds like Elasticsearch (1.x) is still using the original (non-performant) implementation for the FuzzyLikeThisQuery, which is why the edit-distance can increase beyond 2.  However, FuzzyLikeThis has been deprecated as of 1.6 and [won't be supported in 2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10391).